# How do I get the array method to give me the correct output?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to make a method that expects an array of `int` and two `int S1` and `int S2` as parameters. The integers represent the starting position and the ending position of a subarray within the parameter array. The method returns a new array that contains the elements from the starting position to the ending position.

This is what I have, but it keeps giving me this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at testing.subArray(testing.java:14)
    at testing.main(testing.java:9)
```

Here's the code:

```
public class testing{

public static void main(String args[])
{
int[] firstArray = {8,9,10,11,12,13};
subArray(firstArray, 2, 4);
}

public static void subArray(int[]originalArray, int S1, int S2)
{
int[] copy = new int[3];
System.arraycopy(originalArray, S1, copy, S2, 2);

for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
        System.out.println(copy[i]);}
}

}
```

Help please! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method returns a new array that contains the elements from the starting position to the ending position.

At present it doesn't return anything (it's a `void` method). However, you could make use of [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) if you wanted to make your job as easy as possible.

As to your current code, here are some hints:

1. Why are you always allocating three elements for `copy`? The size of the array ought to depend on `S1` and `S2`.
2. The arguments to `arraycopy()` are *completely* wrong. Read the relevant part of the Java documentation and figure out what the correct values are.

Comment: Eeek, sorry... I'm a beginner.. Only about a semester in. I'll work on it, thank you

Comment: I did what you said, but it says it can't find symbol 'Arrays'.
`public static void main(String args[])
{

int[] firstArray = {8,9,10,11,12,13};

subArray(firstArray, 2, 4);
}

public static void subArray(int[]originalArray, int S, int E)
{
 int[]copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalArray,S,E);

 for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
   System.out.println(copy[i]);}
}
`

Comment: @pearbear: This looks a lot better. Note that `copyOfRange()` doesn't copy the end element (`E`) -- you may need to adjust for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that this works much better:

```
public class testing {

    public static final int DEFAULT_LENGTH = 3;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] firstArray = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        int [] subArray = createSubArray(firstArray, 2, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(subArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int [] createSubArray(int[] originalArray, int startPosition1, int valuesToCopy) {
        int subArrayLength = Math.min((originalArray.length-startPosition1), valuesToCopy);
        int [] subArray = new int[subArrayLength];
        System.arraycopy(originalArray, startPosition1, subArray, 0, subArrayLength);

        return subArray;
    }

}
```